# Popup menu with hover class in jQuery (trying to replicate select box with a <ul>)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, removeclass

I've been trying to figure this out for awhile, but I'm just going in circles.

Essentially, I have an input field with 2 options that one can select. This isn't a normal `<select>` option, rather an `<ul>` with 2 `<li>`'s. Which is fine for what I'm doing.

In **state 1**: it's just a normal input form.

In **state** 2: the user hovers over it and can choose the (currently inactive state which in the example below is "exclude").

In **state 3**: The inactive (exclude) option is clicked, and toggled with the currently active (include) state, resulting in exclude now being the active state.

I put this on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ULafm/13/  -- My text toggle isn't working properly on jsfiddle, although it does on my local server where I'm developing).

[image]

The biggest problem is getting rid of the popup from .form-filter .link a:hover and .form-filter .link:hover after the inactive state is clicked like in state 2 of the image above.

I  tried doing `$(".form-filter ul li").removeClass("hover")` and some other variants, like

`$(".form-filter ul .li:hover").css("display", "none")` or

`$(".form-filter ul li a:hover").css("display", "none")` but to no avail.

LinkedIn's search is a similar example to what I'm doing:

[image]

To sum it up in one question: how can I make it so after the text toggles, the hover state disappears to look like state 3?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your fiddle is not working because you have not closed the parenthesis of your DOM ready.

Comment: Woops thanks for catching that! I had it in a function earlier, but took it out to make it easier for people to look @ on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the list to hide after certain events, I would probably control its visibility directly through JS instead of through :hover CSS selectors. Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ULafm/16/

Comment: Elegant and clean solution. Thank you so much! :D

Comment: No problem! This is a common headache for me — you get a nice, 90% solution working with just plain'ol CSS, but can't get that final 10%....